# $(X, d)$ be an infinite compact metric space. Then there exists no function $f : X → X,$ satisfying $d(f(x), f(y)) > d(x, y)$ for all $x \neq y.$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X, d)$ be an infinite compact metric space. Then there exists no function $f : X → X,$ continuous or otherwise, with the property that $d(f(x), f(y)) > d(x, y)$ for all $x \neq y.$
True or False$?$

A Metric Space, , is called compact if every infinite subset has a limit point.

$d(f(x), f(y)) > d(x, y)$ for all $x \neq y$ implies $f$ is injective ( This is something stronger than injectivity).

I read this theorem in Munkres Topology: Let $f : X → Y$ be a continuous
map of the compact metric space $(X, dX )$ to the metric space $(Y, dY ).$ Then $f$ is uniformly continuous. So if $f$ is continuous then the statement is true as the condition $d(f(x), f(y)) > d(x, y)$ for all $x \neq y$ contradicts the uniform continuity of $f$ . What about discontinuous $f?$
Any hint would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Consider the set of points $\{x, f(x), f^2(x), \ldots\}$, where $x$ is a point that is not fixed by $f$ (you'll need to show that such a point exists).

Comment: [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3585506/4280) implies that $f$ is an isometry which gives a contradiction.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, thanks!